# Firestore -- refactor a v8 getQuery for v9

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to refactor [this](https://github.com/shapkar/the-usefirestore-hook) repo (which I'm using as a tutorial for React, Redux and useFirestore) to work with Firestore web version 9. As I plod through the many errors, I'm stuck on this `query.limit is not a function` and I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
import { CollectionReference, Query } from "@firebase/firestore-types";

import { CollectionOptions } from "firebase-config/queryOptions";
import getFirestoreRef from "./getFirestoreRef";

const getQuery = (collection: string, options?: CollectionOptions) => {
  const baseQuery: CollectionReference = getFirestoreRef(collection);
  let query: Query = baseQuery;
  if (options && options.queries) {
    const { queries } = options;
    queries.forEach(({ attribute, operator, value }) => {
      query = query.where(attribute, operator, value);
    });
  }

  if (options && options.sort) {
    const { attribute, order } = options.sort;
    query = query.orderBy(attribute, order);
  }

  if (options && options.limit) {
    query = query.limit(options.limit); // query.limit is not a function
  }

  return query;
};

export default getQuery;
```

Here is my non-working attempt:

```
import { CollectionReference, Query } from "@firebase/firestore-types";
import { limit, orderBy, query, where } from "firebase/firestore";

import { CollectionOptions } from "firebase-config/queryOptions";
import getFirestoreRef from "./getFirestoreRef";

const getQuery = (collection: string, options?: CollectionOptions) => {
  const collectionRef: CollectionReference = getFirestoreRef(collection);
  let q;
  if (options && options.queries) {
    const { queries } = options;
    queries.forEach(({ attribute, operator, value }) => {
      q = query(collectionRef, where(attribute, operator, value));
    });
  }

  if (options && options.sort) {
    const { attribute, order } = options.sort;
    q = query(collectionRef, orderBy(attribute, order));
  }

  if (options && options.limit) {
    q = query(collectionRef, limit(options.limit));
  }

  return q;
};

export default getQuery;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase documentation has side-by-side examples of the v8 and v9 syntax.  If we look there on [querying the database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) and [ordering and limiting data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data), it shows for example that this code in the namespaced API:

> `citiesRef.orderBy("name").limit(3)`

Translates to this in the modular API:

> ```
> import { query, orderBy, limit } from "firebase/firestore";  
>
> const q = query(citiesRef, orderBy("name"), limit(3));
> ```

Which should get you halfway through the conversion already.

For the `where` clauses of the query, you'll want to build an array of them, rather than constantly reassign the `q` variable. You can then pass the array on filter conditions to the `query` function too.

---

**Update** Based on your update, the conditions array would be something like this:

```
let conditions = [];
if (options && options.queries) {
  conditions = options.queries.map(({ attribute, operator, value }) => where(attribute, operator, value));
}
```

It could even be that that inner line can be as simple as:

```
conditions = options.queries.map(where);
```

You'll then have to create the query out of the conditions and the order and limit, when those are present.

Comment: I added my broken attempt.

Comment: Your new attempt builds a new `query` for each condition, but you need a single `query` with an array of `where` conditions, one or more `orderBy` calls and a single `limit` call.

Comment: Thank you Frank. I'm admittedly an intermediate noobie so not quite sure how to create that single, conditional query. I'll dig in.